# Connect to another domain Active Directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am trying to connect to another domain using from my C# code but I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
doLog("Going For establishing Connection");

var username = "cn=Directory Manager";
var password = "somepassword";

using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://10.10.10.132:2232", username, password))
{ 
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        doLog("In the principal searcher");

        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            doLog("Looping result:" + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

It is working in java but from .net it always throw an error on this line

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://10.10.10.132:2232", username, password))
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you try without `ldap://`?

Comment: yes i did and same exception

Comment: try to replace "LDAP://10.10.10.132:2232" by DNS domain name.

Comment: In addition, try pinging the domain name and IP in the command prompt from the same machine where your code is running.

Comment: Is the server using LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) on that port? It could be an error with the certificate. You get this error when that happens. If so, you must use the same domain name that the certificate is issued to when you connect. So if the certificate is issued to "example.com", you must connect with `LDAP://example.com:2232`. But it could also be that the certificate is not trusted on the computer you are connecting from.

Comment: @TawabWakil It is pinging from my local machine, but the error is still the same